# Multiline ouput from command does not assign elements to bash array as expected

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm trying to assign elements to an array using ouput from a command. Every example I've found appears to work perfectly whereas my code is only showing 1 element that looks malformed.

Here is the command with output formatted correctly.

```
[root@probe-eno16777736 nst]# tac "/hns/test_cfg" | sed -n -e "/ip address/,/\!/ p" | grep -B1 "\!" | sed '/!/d' | sed '/\-\-/d'
interface GigabitEthernet0
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2.3249
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2.470
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.3249
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.470
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3419
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
interface Loopback32491
interface Loopback3249
interface Loopback470
```

Here I assign the output to array named "A"

```
[root@probe-eno16777736 nst]# A=($(tac "/hns/test_cfg" | sed -n -e "/ip address/,/\!/ p" | grep -B1 "\!" | sed '/!/d' | sed '/\-\-/d'))
```

Here I try to verify each line outputted from command is an element of the array and clearly this is not the case.

```
[root@probe-eno16777736 nst]# echo ${A[@]}
 interface Loopback47091et0/0/0.3419
```

Comment: Your input file has DOS line endings. Try `echo "${A[@]}" | cat -v` to see them. Also *always* quote variable expansions so `"${A[@]}"` and not `${A[@]}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use proper `IFS`:

```
IFS=$'\n' declare -a arr=($(tac "/hns/test_cfg" | sed -n -e "/ip address/,/\!/ p" | 
                           grep -B1 "\!" | sed -e '/!/d' -e '/--/d' -e 's/\r//'))
```

`IFS=$'\n'` will split the input on newlines while populating array `arr`.

Print the array:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: True but not the issue here. Though it took me a second look to see it.

Comment: declare barked at the portion of the command ouput following the space


[root@probe-eno16777736 nst]# IFS=$'\n' declare -a A=($(tac "/hns/test_cfg" | sed -n -e "/ip address/,/\!/ p" | grep -B1 "\!" | sed '/!/d' | sed '/\-\-/d'))
': not a valid identifier GigabitEthernet0/0/3
': not a valid identifier GigabitEthernet0/0/2.3249
etc.........

Comment: Did you check output of `cat -v` as Etan suggested to make sure there is no `\r` in the input.

Comment: [root@probe-eno16777736 nst]# echo "${A[@]}" | cat -v 

interface GigabitEthernet0^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2.3249^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2.470^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.3249^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.470^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3419^M interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0^M interface Loopback32491^M interface Loopback3249^M interface Loopback470^M

Comment: printf appears to print them correctly.
[root@probe-eno16777736 nst]# printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}"
interface GigabitEthernet0
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2.3249
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2.470
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.3249
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.470
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3419
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
interface Loopback32491
interface Loopback3249
interface Loopback470

Comment: Try this command: `IFS=$'\n' declare -a arr=($(tac "/hns/test_cfg" | sed -n -e "/ip address/,/\!/ p" | grep -B1 "\!" | sed -e '/!/d' -e '/--/d' -e 's/\r//'))`